# perl one liner -add html tags around matched html element

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am using MS word to generate (Web page, filtered) html and have a code style which I want to wrap with `<pre><code>content</pre></code>` to have preformatted text (including tabs and spaces) so visitors can copy and paste code from my site.

I am aware of the cautions / dangers of using regex on html / xml, but, not an issue, since I control content.

Input html looks like this:

`<table class=Code1 PLAIN_MULTILINE_TEXT_AND_FORMATTING</table>`

Output html should look like this:

```
<pre><code>
<table class=Code1 PLAIN_MULTILINE_TEXT_AND_FORMATTING</table>
</pre></code>
```

here is my one-liner, in bash script, $1 is filename:

```
perl -pi -e 's|<table class=Code1 (.*?)</table>|<pre><code><table class=Code1 $1</table></pre></code>|sg' $1
```

Which has no effect. Appears to not match.

Questions:

1 - What is wrong?

2 - Do I need /s (multiline) modifier

3 - Is there a better way (ultimately, will add this to a pre-cache / rendering script, along with existing auto table of contents and auto popup definitions creation)?

site: www.rossco.org

Thanks;
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Perl command line flags to read the entire file instead of line by line: `-0777`

Comment: Thanks, Worked! That's -"zero"777 and, not "oh", do not place between -e and command...

Answer (score -1):

Why not to make the code a little bit more readable? And may be it is not bad idea to have **backup** of original file

```
perl -pi 'orig_*' -0777  -e 's|(<table class=Code1 .*?</table>)|<pre><code>$1</pre></code>|sg' filename
```

Comment: no backup: cuz original file from windoze PC, script on linux/server, already backed up
filename: nada, cuz part of bash script, $1 is filename, batch processing

Comment: Well original post did not specify that this one liner was a part of batch file (I suspected that probably it is). Well then 'orig_*' is unnecessary, retyping also is unnecessary and at least for me my version is easier to understand _wrap_ stored value into `<pre><code>`  **stored value** `</pre></code>`.